# XML Element values showing up blank

Tags: c#, android, xml, linq, xamarin

I'm using Xamarin and LINQ to extract the values of XML elements from a file and display them on screen. The C# program is

```
Button b = (Button)FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button);

    TextView t = (TextView)FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView);

    XDocument X = XDocument.Load(Assets.Open("DataDump.xml"));

    XElement nodex = X.Element("x");
    XElement nodey = X.Element("y");
    XElement nodez = X.Element("z");
    XElement noder = X.Element("RightClick");
    XElement nodel = X.Element("LeftClick");

    b.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {


        t.Text = string.Format(" x={0}\n y={1}\n z={2}", nodex, nodey, nodez);
    };
```

The XML file is

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <x>0.214</x>
  <y>0.396</y>
  <z>9.842</z>
  <LeftClick>1</LeftClick>
  <RightClick>0</RightClick>
</root>
```

The output is:

[image]

I don't get any errors or exceptions, but in the output the values of all the elements show up blank.

How can I get it to display the correct values?

Update: I tried to read around and tinker with my code a bit more, and I think for some reason the program seems to think the values at x, y & z are all null, even though I initialized them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of an `XElement` you can call the [`Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value(v=vs.110).aspx) property

```
var nodex = X.Root.Element("x").Value;
```

or cast to the type that is the value:

```
var nodex = (decimal)X.Root.Element("x");
```

If you load your xml using `XElement.Load` method you are going to load directly the root element of your document, so, you can get the children as you trying to do in your post:

```
XElement X= XElement.Load(Assets.Open("DataDump.xml"));
var nodex = X.Element("x").Value;
//...
```

For more info about this subject take a look this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693120.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`X` is your document.  `Element` returns child elements.  The only child element your document has is `root` - so all your queries will return `null` as none of those child elements exist.

The most obvious fix in this case is to call `Element` on the `root`:

```
X.Root.Element("x")
```